# Update commit message of already pushed patch set

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a patch with some Sets in Gerrit, but would like to change the commit message of the recently pushed patch set. But seems even after updating commit message using `amend` and pushing it to gerrit creates a new Patch Set instead of updating previous one.

So is it possible to edit commit message of last patch without adding a new patch set?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not. But why does it matter? Why do you care if this is a new patchset?

Comment: @Mureinik because it makes it hard to follow the review process

Comment: Did you try with a rebase? I am not an expert with gerrit so I don't really know if it's goign to work but if you want I can answer you like it was on github where it'll definately work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It isn't possible to edit the commit message of last patch without adding a new patchset.

I don't know exactly what is your issue about the new patchset but... it's possible to configure Gerrit in the way that it won't require to review again a previously approved patchset if only the commit message is different.

See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange).

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit will update existing review with a new patchset as long as the *Change-Id* field remains the same.

EDIT: I see you've edited your question. No, it's not possible to update commit message without creating new patchset.

Comment: No. That would be the same **change** but a different **patchset**.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I have written.